# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 software updater fails

Tags: updates, update-manager, mate

Edit with additional info prior to log dump:

I have a recent install (fresh, rather than an upgrade) of Ubuntu Mate 20.04, and it has been working just fine (it's still running OK for the most part), but as of today, I notice that it does not run updates.

If I kick off the updater, it checks and tells me that a number of updates are ready, but as soon as I click the update button, it crashes out. This is the content of /var/log/syslog from the moment of clicking the button to it dying.

Can anyone offer an avenue for investigation here? Or better, of course, a fix!?

Edit: I tried again, and deselected proposed updates and discovered that the actual updates would proceed successfully. What is causing the problem is the "Unused kernel updates to be removed". I tried deselecting the first three, and it crashed, then I ran it again and tried deselecting the last three, and it still crashed. So it seems like the removal process is the cause of the problem, perhaps rather than any one of these things?

[image: Problematic updates]

```
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop AptDaemon: INFO: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33'), dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-33-generic')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('google-chrome-stable'), dbus.String('openssh-client'), dbus.String('remmina'), dbus.String('remmina-common'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-rdp'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-secret'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-spice'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-vnc')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop org.debian.apt[10246]: 12:00:30 AptDaemon [INFO]: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33'), dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-33-generic')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('google-chrome-stable'), dbus.String('openssh-client'), dbus.String('remmina'), dbus.String('remmina-common'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-rdp'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-secret'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-spice'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-vnc')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/158efe4ae3eb407e9676eb858e771ef0
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop org.debian.apt[10246]: 12:00:30 AptDaemon.Trans [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/158efe4ae3eb407e9676eb858e771ef0
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/158efe4ae3eb407e9676eb858e771ef0
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop org.debian.apt[10246]: 12:00:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/158efe4ae3eb407e9676eb858e771ef0
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Committing packages: dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33'), dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-33-generic')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('google-chrome-stable'), dbus.String('openssh-client'), dbus.String('remmina'), dbus.String('remmina-common'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-rdp'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-secret'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-spice'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-vnc')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop org.debian.apt[10246]: 12:00:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Committing packages: dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33'), dbus.String('linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic'), dbus.String('linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-33-generic')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('google-chrome-stable'), dbus.String('openssh-client'), dbus.String('remmina'), dbus.String('remmina-common'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-rdp'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-secret'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-spice'), dbus.String('remmina-plugin-vnc')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop kernel: [ 6867.112844] polkitd[7272]: segfault at 8 ip 000055b36706d846 sp 00007ffc1f932a30 error 4 in polkitd[55b367068000+f000]
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop kernel: [ 6867.112858] Code: 60 c7 ff ff 4d 89 e5 48 89 44 24 08 eb 53 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 44 24 10 48 89 e9 be 10 00 00 00 31 ff 48 8d 15 1b af 00 00 <4c> 8b 40 08 31 c0 e8 bf cb ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 10 e8 75 c9 ff ff 4c
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop systemd[1]: polkit.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Jun 28 12:00:30 simon-laptop systemd[1]: polkit.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt autoremove`. Post the output here.  If you're not sure about the list of packages to be autoremoved, you can stop it by saying "N" instead of "Y" to continue

Comment: Bingo. The command-line version ran without complaint, and now the GUI update runs and says nothing needs to be done. So, hopefully it'll work correctly next time, and all will be well. Thanks--I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of this :( Would you like to put your comment in an answer so I can mark it as "accepted"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also remove unused or outdated packages using the command line.

Open a terminal and run the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
```

The `update` command will update the list of available packages.

The `autoremove` command will remove orphaned and outdated packages that are no longer needed.